# Como excluir itens do HTML usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um exercício em que tenho que criar uma lista de itens usando HTML e uma função para excluir itens da lista.
A função deve usar o input do tipo submit para excluir o item inteiro do HTML sem excluir outro item da lista. 
Criei à lista e a função, mas não está funcionando. Podem me ajudar? Obrigado.

```
<script>
  const produto = document.querySelector(".produto");

  //Função para excluir um item da lista
  const excluirProduto =
    ("submit",
    (event) => {
      if (event.target.contains(".produto")) {
        produto.innerHTML = ``;
      }
    });
</script>


<body>
<div class="listaDeItens">
  <div class="produto">
    <input type="submit" value="EXCLUIR" />
    <p class="descricaoProduto">ITEM QUE DEVE SER EXCLUIDO</p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="produto">
    <input type="submit" value="EXCLUIR" />
    <p class="descricaoProduto">ITEM QUE DEVE SER EXCLUIDO</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns problemas no teu código:

- usa botões, é mais semântico e para além disso o evento `submit` tem de ser interrompido para evitar recarregar a página
- `const produto = document.querySelector(".produto");` carrega 1 só produto, tens vários... terias de usar `querySelectorAll` e iterar para amarrar um auscultador de eventos
- `produto.innerHTML = ''` não remove o produto, só o esvazia de conteúdo

Sugestão:

- usa botões com `onclick``
- procura o `.produto` desse botão com `.closest`
- usa `.remove()` que é feito para remover elementos do DOM

```js
//Função para excluir um item da lista
const excluirProduto = btn => btn.closest('.produto').remove();
```

```html
<div class="listaDeItens">
  <div class="produto">
    <button type="button" value="EXCLUIR" onclick="excluirProduto(this)" />
    <p class="descricaoProduto">ITEM QUE DEVE SER EXCLUIDO</p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="produto">
    <button type="button" value="EXCLUIR" onclick="excluirProduto(this)" />
    <p class="descricaoProduto">ITEM QUE DEVE SER EXCLUIDO</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gostei de mais! Obrigado.